# Persist cookies across NightmareJS instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

How would I persist and pass cookies along multiple NightmareJS instances?
Any example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how you would set up a session with some cookies saved from earlier sessions.

```
// create a promise for retrieving cookies
function getCookies(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    Nightmare()
      .goto(url)
      .cookies.get() // get the cookies
      .end()
      .then(resolve)
  });
}

var COOKIES;
getCookies(url).then(function (cookies) {
  // save your cookies somewhere...

  // you could save them in the file system (with NodeJs) 
  require('fs').writeFileSync(
   'cookies.json',
   JSON.stringify(cookies)
  );

  // or you could set a global variable
  COOKIES = cookies;
})

// and now each time you want to use these cookies
// you would simply set them before each session
function google() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    Nightmare()
      .goto('about:blank') // create your session by going to a blank page
      .cookies.set(COOKIES) // or .cookies.set(require('fs').readFileSync('cookies.json'))
      .goto('http://google.com')
      // do your thing with the new cookies..
      .end()
      .then(resolve)
  })
}
```

Comment: `cookie.set(COOKIES)` won't work I suppose since its an object or cookies and not a single cookie, have to loop right?

Comment: It will work because cookies.set(cookiesArray) can accept array of cookie objects. 
https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#cookiessetcookies